# updating xml node with JDOM

Tags: java, xml, jdom

I have problem with updating data in my xml file.

My xml file looks like this :

```
<root>
 <info>
 .....
 </info>
  <OBJECT_TYPE>x2000</OBJECT_TYPE>
  <prop>
    <DESCRIPTION>fast train</DESCRIPTION>
    <PARENT>NULL</PARENT>
    <VIRTUAL>0</VIRTUAL>
    <VISIBLE>1</VISIBLE>
    <PICTURE>NULL</PICTURE>
    <HELP>NULL</HELP>
    <MIN_NO>1</MIN_NO>
    <MAX_NO>1</MAX_NO>
    <NAME_FORMAT>NULL</NAME_FORMAT>
  </prop>
<param>
  <PARAMETER>nidbrc</PARAMETER>
  <DATA_TYPE>String</DATA_TYPE>
  <DESCRIPTION>super fast</DESCRIPTION>
  <MIN_NO>1</MIN_NO>
  <MAX_NO>1</MAX_NO>
  <ORDER1>1</ORDER1>
  <NESTED>1</NESTED>
  <DEFAULT1>NULL</DEFAULT1>
  <FORMAT>100:45</FORMAT>
</param>
<param>
</param>
<param>
</param>
<param>
</param>
...
</type>
<type>
  ... 
 </type>
 <type>
</root>
```

Here i am trying to get my first param from type number 1 and updating the first  parameter of 9

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        File xml = new File("test.xml");

        try {
            XMLOutputter xmlOut = new XMLOutputter();
            Document doc = (Document) new SAXBuilder().build(xml);
            Element rootNode = doc.getRootElement();
            Element typeContent = rootNode.getChildren().get(1);
            System.out.println("typeContent : " + typeContent.getChildren());

            for (int i = 0; i < typeContent.getContentSize(); i++) {

                List<Element> list = typeContent.getChildren("param");

                if (list.size() > 0) {
                    Element element = list.get(1);
                    List paramChilds = element.getChildren("PARAMETER");

                    for (int j = 0; j < paramChilds.size(); j++) {

                        Element node = (Element) paramChilds.get(j);
                        System.out.println(node.getText());
                        // xmlOut.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());
                        // xmlOut.output(doc, new FileWriter("test.xml"));
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException io) {
            System.out.println(io.getMessage());
        } catch (JDOMException jdomex) {
            System.out.println(jdomex.getMessage());
        }
```

What I find hard is to know how to dig into the xml file and therefore this one aint working but this one is null :     node.getChild("PARAMETER").setText("Bla");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my complete solution :

```
public void updateParameters(int index, int row, int column,
            String columnName, Object data) throws Exception {

        int objTypeIndex = index + 1;

        File xml = new File("xmlFiles/CoreDatamodel.xml");

        try {
            XMLOutputter xmlOut = new XMLOutputter();
            org.jdom2.Document doc = new SAXBuilder().build(xml);
            Namespace ns = Namespace.getNamespace("http://www.bombardier.com");
            org.jdom2.Element rootNode = doc.getRootElement();
            org.jdom2.Element typeContent = rootNode.getChildren().get(
                    objTypeIndex);

            List<Element> list = typeContent.getChildren("param", ns);

            if (list.size() > 0) {
                Element element = list.get(row);
                List paramChilds = element.getChildren(columnName, ns);

                Element node = (Element) paramChilds.get(0);
                node.setText(data.toString());
                System.out.println(node.getText());
                xmlOut.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());
                xmlOut.output(doc, new FileWriter("xmlFiles/CoreDatamodel.xml"));

            }

        } catch (IOException io) {
            System.out.println(io.getMessage());
        } catch (JDOMException jdomex) {
            System.out.println(jdomex.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could either loop all 'param' children like this:

```
Document doc = (Document) new SAXBuilder().build(xml);
Element rootNode = doc.getRootElement();

// get all 'param' children
List<Element> paramElements = root.getChildren("param");
for (Element param: paramElements) {
    // do something intelligent
    param.getChild("PARAMETER").setText("Bla");
}

// write to file
xmlOut.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());
xmlOut.output(doc, new FileWriter("test.xml"));
```

Or you could use xpath to search for the elements and do stuff with it; [example](http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/12/17/how-to-use-xpath-expression-to-find-attributes-in-jdom-xml-document/).

Comment: That wont work. And xpath is just as tricky. I have tried it and had an example query somewhere but it didnt work neither.

Comment: what do you mean by 'wont work'? Errors? unexpected behavior? what exactly?

Comment: @Sembrano I agree with R. Oosterholt. use `root.getChildren("param")` not `typeContent.getChildren("param")` (and also agree that XPath is a good thing).

Comment: I solved it my problem was I had forgot the namespace.

Comment: I posted the complete solution

Answer (score 1):

Here, you appear to be trying to set the text of the first `PARAMETER` element which is a child of the first `PARAMETER` element that is a child of the second child of the `root` element.

```
Element rootNode = doc.getRootElement();
...
Element typeContent = rootNode.getChildren().get(1);
...
Element node = typeContent.getChild("PARAMETER");
node.getChild("PARAMETER").setText("Bla");
```

No such element appears to exist in your example xml.

1. `typeContent` corresponds to the element `<OBJECT_TYPE>x2000</OBJECT_TYPE>`, which has no `PARAMETER` element children.
2. There are no `PARAMETER` elements that are children of
   `PARAMETER` elements.

What's more, for some reason you seem to be doing exactly the same thing 15 times.  Why is that?

Comment: Yes I updated the code but as soon as I am trying to fetch my param child  List<Element> list = typeContent.getChildren("param"); then its null. Like it doesnt exist. but i deost exist when I am printing it out : System.out.println("typeContent : " + typeContent.getChildren());

Comment: Are you sure it's null, not an empty list?

Comment: Its typing out like this : typeContent : [[Element: <OBJECT_TYPE [Namespace: http://www.bombardier.com]/>], [Element: <prop [Namespace: http://www.bombardier.com]/>], [Element: <param [Namespace: http://www.bombardier.com]/>], [Element: <param [Namespace: http://www.bombardier.com]/>], [Element: <param [Namespace: http://www.bombardier.com]/>], [Element: <param [Namespace: http://www.bombardier.com]/>], [Element: <param [Namespace: http://www.bombardier.com]/>], [Element: <param [Namespace: http://www.bombardier.com]/>], [Element: <param  but then it never fetches the params

Comment: Where did that namespace come from?  It's not mentioned in your example XML.  You will need to use the two-argument form of [getChildren](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/Element.html#getChildren()), in order to specify the namespace.

Comment: Dunno I guess its from my root tag that has some xmlns stuffs and links to schema.

Comment: There are no namespace declarations on the root tag in your example.  If the real xml has namespaces, then these are not irrelevant.  You will need to use the value from xmlns="" as the second argument.

Comment: <root xmlns="http://www.bombardier.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bombardier.com DMP.xsd"> so ill do like this? or do I need to use them all? : Namespace ns = Namespace.getNamespace("http://www.bombardier.com");

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `param` Elements like this:

```
List<Element> list = typeContent.getChildren("param");
```

But `typeContent` does not have any `param` children. `typeContent` is:

```
Element typeContent = rootNode.getChildren().get(1);
```

which, as far as I can tell, is:

```
<OBJECT_TYPE>x2000</OBJECT_TYPE>
```

You should, I guess, be looking for the `param` children like:

```
List<Element> paramElements = root.getChildren("param");
```

You ***should*** be using JDOM2 and not JDOM. With JDOM2 your XPath option is much simpler:

```
XPathExpression<Element> paramxpath = XPathFactory.instance()
         .compile("/root/param", Filters.element());
for (Element param : paramxpath.evaluate(doc)) {
    System.out.println(param.getText());
}
```